# Swift Quiz - reset button

Tags: swift

i followed one quiz tutorial and everything works, but when i want to add  reset button so quiz can start again it doesn't work. Here's the code, i tried to reset numbers, i tried with emptying array but it doesn't work. Help pls.

```
import UIKit

struct Question {
var Question : String!
var Answers : [String]!
var Answer : Int!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var qLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var novceki: UILabel!

var Questions = [Question]()

var Qnumber = Int()

var AnswerNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    Questions = [Question(Question: "Jesi pojeo?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "Najvisi vrh piramide?" , Answers: ["10", "39", "40", "55"], Answer: 2),
        Question(Question: "Jesi popusio?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "Jesi bio vani?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 3)]

    pickQuestion()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func pickQuestion (){

 if Questions.count > 0{
        //Qnumber = 0
        Qnumber = random() % Questions.count
        qLabel.text = Questions[Qnumber].Question

        AnswerNumber = Questions[Qnumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[Qnumber].Answers[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        Questions.removeAtIndex(Qnumber)
}
    else {
        NSLog("Done!")
    }
}


@IBAction func Btn1(sender: UIButton) {

    if AnswerNumber == 0 {
        pickQuestion()
    }
    else{

        NSLog("CORRECT!")
    }
}

@IBAction func Btn2(sender: UIButton) {
    if AnswerNumber == 1 {
        pickQuestion()
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Wrong!")
    }
}

@IBAction func Btn3(sender: UIButton) {
    if AnswerNumber == 2 {
        pickQuestion()
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Wrong!")
    }
}

@IBAction func Btn4(sender: UIButton) {
    if AnswerNumber == 3 {
        pickQuestion()
    }
    else{
        NSLog("Wrong!")
    }
}
@IBAction func reset(sender: UIButton) {
    pickQuestion()  //- here is the problem, what to put here? it only continue with quiz it does not restart it, tried with reset numbers and array, but don't work
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function to regenerate your questions:

```
func freshQuestions() -> [Questions] {
    return [Question(Question: "Jesi pojeo?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "Najvisi vrh piramide?" , Answers: ["10", "39", "40", "55"], Answer: 2),
        Question(Question: "Jesi popusio?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "Jesi bio vani?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 3)]
}
```

Change your viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Questions = freshQuestions()
    pickQuestion()    
}
```

Then:

```
@IBAction func reset(sender: UIButton) {
    Questions = freshQuestions()
    QNumber = 0
    pickQuestion()  //- here is the problem, what to put here? it only continue with quiz it does not restart it, tried with reset numbers and array, but don't work
 }
```

It is even nicer if you wrap those two new lines in the reset-function in their own `resetQuiz()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your reset button needs to repopulate your array of questions, because each time you call `pickQuestion()`, you are removing questions from the array.

You can redeclare the array by adding this to your reset function.

```
Questions = [Question(Question: "Jesi pojeo?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "Najvisi vrh piramide?" , Answers: ["10", "39", "40", "55"], Answer: 2),
        Question(Question: "Jesi popusio?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 0),
        Question(Question: "Jesi bio vani?" , Answers: ["Jesam", "Nisam", "Budem", "Fuj"], Answer: 3)]
```

Ideally, to reduce repeated code, you should refactor the population of the questions array into its own function.